# htaccess redirect from variable URL to clean URL

Tags: .htaccess, variables, redirect

I have a site that had URLs that looked like this all from the index.php page. It was a first attempt at writing for databases several years ago.

www.domain.com/index.php?p=page1
www.domain.com/index.php?p=page2

I have changed to a wordpress site and want to redirect anyone accessing the page to the new url. Such as

www.domain.com/page1
www.domain.com/cat/page2

I have the redirect written like this but it just redirects every one to the home page.

```
Redirect 301 /index.php?p=page2 http://www.domain.com/page_newname_2/
```

Thanks for any help, I have searched and can't seem to find an answer that is close or makes sense.

-Brian

Comment: there is also this at the top of htaccess file. Forum limited me to 2 links in post.
Redirect 301 /index.php?p=home http://www.domain.com/

Answer (score 1):

Redirect old page to new post page using Wordpress!

if so, go to plugins, add new, enter Redirection. The very first plugin by John Godley will do just what you need.

Manual download page for plugin [redirection](http://urbangiraffe.com/plugins/redirection/)

after installing you will find it in Tools -> Redirection

Comment: The old website was not wordpress but this works perfect, Thanks soo much!!!!! I've been waiting on an answer in another forum for a few weeks and a few minutes here and I get a perfect solution amazing!

Comment: @BrianYork If you are satisfied with the answer, you should consider [**accepting**](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) it, selecting the check mark in the upper left of this answer.